# Как прочитать определенную строку, не читая весь файл?

Tags: perl

Возможно ли на перле прочитать строку 82158622 из очень большого файла, не читая весь файл? (строки фиксированного размера)

Не подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать? Слышал, что перл позволяет прочитать какую-то строку, не читая файл полностью, если все строки фиксированного размера.

Comment: Если все строки фиксированного размера и известен размер перевода строки (под виндой — 2 байта, под остальными — 1 байт), то можно вычислить необходимую позицию в файле в байтах, а дальше воспользоваться функцией `seek`, чтобы начать читать с середины файла.

Comment: @yeputons можете плиз оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Perl (да и в других языках) обычно есть функция, позволяющая читать с определённого места файла. В Perl она называется `seek` — перемещает текущий указатель внутри файла на определённую позицию (можно задавать относительно начала, конца или текущего положения в файле).

Если у вас все строки фиксированного размера и известен размер перевода строки (под виндой — 2 байта, под остальными — 1 байт), то можно вычислить необходимую позицию в файле в байтах, а дальше после открытия файла вызвать функцию `seek` и дальше читать как обычно, чтение будет начато с позиции, которую передали в `seek`.